# converting object to str and back to objects

Tags: python, string, object

i had a list of obj

```
[<DiffMatchPatch.patch_obj instance at 0x152a0b00>, <DiffMatchPatch.patch_obj instance at 0x152a0ab8>]
```

i later converted them to a strs - then i got

```
["@@ -797,44 +797,8 @@\n :  %0A\n-       print 'WithDrwaing %25d' %25 shs%0A\n     \n", "@@ -854,158 +854,4 @@\n e %0A%0A\n-'''%0Aif __name__ == '__main__': %0A       b=Transcations(amount=9) %0A       b.deposit() %0A       b.withdraw(2000) %0A       b.interest(30) %0A       b.chk()%0A'''%0A%0A%0A\n"]
```

is it possible to convert the strs back to objects?

Comment: did you loose your original list?

Comment: No - i have the original list, was only wondering if there is way to do this

Answer (score 1):

You must use Pickle for this purpose...

```
from cPickle import dumps, loads

lst = [1,2,3]
pckld = dumps(lst)

print (pckld)
>> '(lp1\nI1\naI2\naI3\na.'

loads(pckld)
>> [1,2,3]
```

Comment: thanks for this response, thought there could be a another way other than pickle

Comment: Right way to convert an object (or anything except char, string, and numeric values) to string and back is really hard and have possible bad effects (like data loss). Otherwise you probably have to write a module to make the convcertion...

Answer (score 0):

Although it is not exactly what you ask for, maybe the "serialization" can solve your problems:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization

http://docs.python.org/library/marshal.html

http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html

Also, you can think about defining your own __ str __ function and a constructor that will spawn an object from the string (created by __ str __)